# Unable to get textArea of type resizableTextArea in TSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am unable to get `textArea` of type `resizableTextArea` in TSX.

Here is my code:

```
const textAreaRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);
const resizableTextArea = textAreaRef.current.resizableTextArea
```

This is the error that I get:

```
TS2339: Property 'resizableTextArea' does not exist on type 'HTMLTextAreaElement'.
```

I don't have a way to do that other than to define the type as any.

Comment: Are you rendering a standard dom `<textarea>`? If so, then they don't have a property named resizableTextArea, so it seems typescript is giving you a valid error. If you're rendering some custom component instead, you'll need to tell us what that is.

Comment: The textarea I am using is from the component library of Ant of Design , so I should look up the type in the component library declaration file, right?

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the relevant declaration file from the Ant of Design component library :)